# unitialized local variable + using unitialized memory

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    int secretnum = 7;
    int Guess;

    while (secretnum != Guess) {
        cout << "Enter guess: ";
        cin >> Guess; 
    }

    cout << "You win";

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get 1 warning and 1 error.

Warning: Using uninitialized memory "Guess"

Error: uninitialized local variable "Guess" used

Comment: Yup, and what is your question

Comment: Also, post all errors in the question as text.

Comment: Change to a `do/while`.

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Put the messages as text in the actual question instead of linking to an external picture.

Comment: There error tells you enough

Comment: Obviously, if you use a variable before you assign a value to it, that will be potentially problematic.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you use the value of *Guess* (in the while statement) before you put any value into it.

As a rule of thumb, you should initialize your variables when defined, meaning:

```
int guess = 0;
```

Is better than:

```
int guess; // This memory is uninitialized!
```

Currently, the value in guess is whatever in that memory, and shouldn't be used!

In order to be as clear as possible - I agree that do...while is preferable over while in this context, I want to add that initializing is important nonetheless:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    constexpr int secretnum = 7;
    int guess = (secretnum == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) 
              ? secretnum + 1 
              : secretnum - 1;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter a guess: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> guess; 
    } while (secretnum != guess);

    std::cout << "You win" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Specifically, in this code, do ... while would fix the error, but in common practice, not initializing memory in definition is a bad habit. Even if i use do...while, I do put something in this memory before using it (as a safety measure, you can never know how the code will be changed in the future).

Comment: So make it: '''secretnum + 1'''

Comment: I haven't said you should avoid do...while. I just said that **in addition** you should always initialize your variables! Also, just make it secrenum+1 if it is at maximum... the fix is easy.

Comment: I also never said *not* to initialize `guess`. However, now that `do` / `while` is used, the complex initialization of `guess` isn't necessary. `int guess = 0;` is no longer problematic because the user overwrites `guess` before the first comparison anyway.

Comment: Since it is constexpr, it doesn't change the compiled code.

Comment: Sure. But it's needless complexity. It has zero positive impact. You could add noise to the code arbitrarly, but doing so isn't an improvement. `int guess {};` is clean, short, safe and functionnal.

Comment: If the condition `secretnum == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` is `true` you have undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow in `secretnum + 1` so not only is it unnecessarily complex, it's also wrong.